# I/O failure with Android Nougat (7.0)

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im getting this error only with the android version 7.0 using Parse Android SDK.

With <7 and 7.1.1 its working nice, but with 7.0 the error is just `I/O failure` retrieved but the query exception

Tried with parse-android `1.14.0` & `1.15.6`.

I have internet, because displaying a webview is working ok.

Any idea?

My parse query:

```
public static void getPatrocinadores(final APIResponseListener listener) {
ParseQuery<Patrocinador> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(API_PATROCINADOR);
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("visible", true);
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Patrocinador>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Patrocinador> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            listener.onSuccess(objects);
        } else {
            listener.onError(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Interceptor log:

```
D/OkHttp: User-Agent: Parse Android SDK 1.15.6 (com.prueba.package/3) API Level 24
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://prueba.parse.com/1/classes/Patrocinador http/1.1
```

Comment: If you provide information on what you're doing to actually get this error, you may get an answer that allows you to be on the latest SDKs, which would be recommended.

Comment: @JakeT. ok, i have added more info

Comment: That looks like a problem with your Parse initialiation.  Parse.com is dead, you shouldn't be trying to access prueba.parse.com.  You should be trying to access your own server.

Comment: Our parse server its running ok, We have our own servers, "prueba.parse.com" is just a fake domain

Answer (score 0):

My solution: use the version 1.13.1

If you dont want to change the version another solution here:

[Android 7 dosnt allow my letsencrypt SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963709/android-7-dosnt-allow-my-letsencrypt-ssl/43968086#43968086)